# Unable to return the body from a callback function

Tags: node.js, promise, jwt

I am attempting to assign the body of the callback function to assign it to a variable.

```
const request = require('request');


async function getAPIToken(options){
    let token = await request(options, (error, response, body)=> {return body})
    return token
}

let token1 = getAPIToken(options);
console.log(token1)
```

This returns promise pending, however when I use token1.then((a)=> {console.log(a)}) it returns the request not the body.

Comment: Did you read about `async/await` support in `request` package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait ?

Comment: Also please pay attention that `request` package is deprecated. I recommend you to use something like `axios` or `got`